# After upgrade to Jessie, service control doesn't return result

Tags: systemd, raspbian

Actually not debian, but Raspbian Wheezy to Raspbian Jessie.
I upgrade it using some commands which found on Raspbian official forum.

cat /etc/debian_version = 8.0.

The problem is, I can't view any result when I restart the service.

Before upgrade(Wheezy):

```
# service tor restart
[ok] cccc
[ok] ddd
# _
```

After upgrade(Jessie):

```
# service tor restart
# _
```

And all results are written to /var/log/syslog...
How can I revert this thing? I want to see actual result, not written to log.

Answer (score 4):

`service` is now handled by systemd, and systemd is quiet when everything goes well. There doesn't seem to be a way to change that. Lennart [added a TODO item](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-November/007482.html) to add a verbose mode restoring behaviour similar to what you're after, but three years later it's still [in the TODO list](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/d82047bef5b8a35fb2d1d4685f241383df1a1d76/TODO#L571)!

You could always define a shell function to do something like

```
service tor restart && echo '[OK]' || echo '[Failed]'
```

(with `tor` replaced by `$1`, and whatever message you want in the `echo` commands), but that won't give you details of units running multiple commands.

```
systemctl status tor
```

will show you the detailed status of the relevant unit, so another option could be to couple that with `start` or `restart`.

Comment: For some services this is "good", but that do not work for a lot of services on error, some services always return sucess, even if the service not started, because systemd is starting a kind of service manager instead of the service itself..... And no dont trust service status about what hapenned I get a lot of times a "STARTED OK" and service is really not running without any feedback! So it still does not solve the problem! But is better if you run journal -xe lot better than doing this, but not good enough because you need to run it everytime and remember of it....

Comment: I agree, the workaround given here is imperfect. This really needs to be implemented in `systemctl`, and units need to be written correctly to properly report the service’s status (which is another issue).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback so it is a general problem! So sad!

Answer (score 0):

> A lot of services on error, some services always return sucess, even if the service not started, because systemd is starting a kind of service manager instead of the service itself..... And no dont trust service status about what hapenned I get a lot of times a "STARTED OK" and service is really not running without any feedback! So it still does not solve the problem! But is better if you run journal -xe lot better than doing this, but not good enough because you need to run it everytime and remember of it. – @Luciano Andress Martini

"No result" means the operation succeeded.  This is the UNIX default.  It is how the `cp` or `rm` commands behave, for example.

If your service is written incorrectly, it may return success and then fail immediately afterwards e.g. when it reads a bad configuration.  This is a bug in the service!  If a sysvinit script behaves like this, you would have exactly the same problem!  There is nothing `systemd` can do to fix that.

When your unit fails, there is a trick to view the last 10 lines from your daemon only.   Run `systemctl status` as the root user (i.e. `sudo`).  Alternatively, you can add your user as a member of one of the groups `systemd-journal` or `adm`.

When I need more than the last 10 lines, I use `journalctl -u tor -b`, meaning everything from the current boot.  Or if you have restarted it many times during the current boot, you might want to use `journalctl -u tor --since=-1hour`.  Or for short, `--since=-1h`.

I think `systemctl` already suggests you run `systemctl status` when the unit fails to start.  (Unfortunately, systemctl never mentions the permissions issue).

`systemctl` does also suggest `journalctl -xe`.   Personally, I think this is unhelpful.  `-x` mostly just adds a lot of noise.  `-e` skips e.g. stdout/stderr messages and anything else that is not explicitly marked as an error message.  (It even skips stderr messages, sorry.  Changing this is awkward: it would allow stderr lines to be re-ordered v.s. stdout, which might be undesirable for shell scripts).

---

There is a similar user complaint [on the systemd issue tracker](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9557), which involves some other services which are buggy.  (Or, one of them looks like it might be *deliberately* failing "in the background", after a long network timeout.  Again, this is exactly how the service is written, it is not systemd trying to annoy you).